# Visual Studio Community does not recognise double type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

```
using System;

namespace Excellent_Result
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double grade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (grade >= 5.50)
                Console.WriteLine("Excellent!");
        }
    }
}
```

I swear this is an extremely simple homework problem, but it gives me an error on the double type?

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

This is the exception and I'm not fond of Visual Studio, so I'm not sure how to set it. The university's system recognises this code as correctly written and working.

Comment: What's your input _double_ value string? It's obviously erroneously.

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Super User.  Programming questions belong on Stack Overflow.  Your error is caused by syntax error and has nothing to do with the fact your using Visual Studio to compile your C# code.

Comment: Yes, it's because of the use of "." instead of "," (for example 5.55 instead of 5,55). I need to change that through the settings somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your double.parse not worked.

Try to convert input string in double like below:

**double grade = convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());**